# Enviar variáveis via GET por php Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Estou criando uma página em PHP que faz uma consulta em um JSON/PHP via ajax e preciso que ela envie para a URL, as variáveis do formulário para que consiga fazer uma consulta neste JSON/PHP.

**HTML:**

```
    <form method="GET" name="formularioBusca"> <input type="text" id="from-airport" name="Origem" class="form-control" placeholder="Onde você esta?"  autocomplete="off" required="required">
<input type="text" id="to-airport" name="Destino" class="form-control" placeholder="Para onde você quer ir?" autocomplete="off" required="required">
<button class="btn btn-buscar-voos" id="buscarVoos" >BUSCAR VOOS</button></form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$('#from-airport').blur(function(){
    $('#buscarVoos').on('click', function(e){
        $('#from-airport').blur(function(){
            var partida = $(this).val();
            var palavras = partida.split(' ');
            var origem = [palavras.pop()];
            sigla = origem.toString().replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
            console.log(sigla);
        })
        $('#to-airport').blur(function(){
            var destino = $(this).val();
            var saida = destino.split(' ');
            var origem = [saida.pop()];
            siglaDestino = origem.toString().replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
            console.log(siglaDestino);
        })
    $.ajax({
                  url: 'api.php',
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'html'
                })
                .done(function(data){
                  console.log(data);  
                  $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
                  $('#exibeVoos').html(data); 
                  $('#modal-loader').hide(); 
                })
                .fail(function(){
                  $('#dynamic-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Aguarde...');
                  $('#modal-loader').hide();
                });
    })
})
```

Comment: É necessário criar um botão ou verificar se ambos os campos estão preenchidos. Da forma que você está fazendo, você está enviando os dados antes mesmo deles serem preenchidos.

Comment: Ah sim, me esqueci de colocar na pergunta, 

$('#buscarVoos').on('click', function(e){..
.....
})

Comment: Se possível clica em [edit] e altere seu código, caso necessário.

Comment: Alterei, Obrigado! =)

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar dados com o `jQuery.ajax`, basta informar o atributo `data` na configuração. Esse atributo irá conter as informações que deverão ser enviadas, tanto via POST, quanto GET, por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $("form[name=\"formularioBusca\"]").serialize()
})
```

O `$(elemento).serialize();` serve para capturar e converter (para o padrão `application/www-url-encoded`), todos os campos do formulário.

Já no HTML, é necessário adicionar o atributo `type="button"` para o elemento do botão. Isso fará com que o cliente não seja redirecionado ao clica-lo.

**Html:**

```
<form method="GET" name="formularioBusca">
    <input type="text" id="from-airport" name="Origem" class="form-control" placeholder="Onde você esta?"  autocomplete="off" required="required">
    <input type="text" id="to-airport" name="Destino" class="form-control" placeholder="Para onde você quer ir?" autocomplete="off" required="required">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-buscar-voos" id="buscarVoos" >BUSCAR VOOS</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    const URL_SEARCH = new URL(location.href);

    $("from-airport").val( URL_SEARCH.searchParams.get("Origem") );
    $("to-airport").val( URL_SEARCH.searchParams.get("Destino") );

    $('#from-airport').blur(function() {
        let partida = $(this).val();
        let palavras = partida.split(' ');
        let origem = [palavras.pop()];
        sigla = origem.toString().replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");

        console.log(sigla);
    })
    $('#to-airport').blur(function() {
        let destino = $(this).val();
        let saida = destino.split(' ');
        let origem = [saida.pop()];
        siglaDestino = origem.toString().replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");

        console.log(siglaDestino);
    })

    $('#buscarVoos').on('click', function(e) {

        history.pushState(null, null, "?" + $("form[name=\"formularioBusca\"]").serialize())

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $("form[name=\"formularioBusca\"]").serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#dynamic-content').html('');
            $('#exibeVoos').html(data);
            $('#modal-loader').hide();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $('#dynamic-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Aguarde...');
            $('#modal-loader').hide();
        });
    })
})
```

Dessa forma, o a sua requisição será enviada para: `http://www.YOUR-SITE.com/api.php?Origem=teste-origem&Destino=teste-destino`, porém o usuário não irá ver essa requisição.

Caso você queira mudar a URL também (e sem redirecionar), basta utilizar o `history.pushState`, por exemplo:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "?" + $("form[name=\"formularioBusca\"]").serialize())
```

E para capturar a URL do usuário e preencher em seu formulário, basta utilizar a API [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

> Caso seu formulário venha conter um campo para upload, recomendo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279834/99718.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas ele não esta gerando a URL a cada vez que eu clico no "BUSCAR"  com os parametros, e meu formulário não tem campo de upload

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli O jQuery fará isso automaticamente, mas caso isso seja realmente necessário... Editei minha resposta respondendo a isso.

Comment: Entendo, mas toda vez que se clica no botão é necessário gerar um URL com os parametros que foram preenchidos como esta imagem https://prnt.sc/ipbws3

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli Os parâmetros são gerados, só não é mostrado para o usuário (essa é uma das funções do `jQuery.ajax`), caso contrário bastaria remover o evento `click` do botão e adicionar o atributo `action="api.php"` no elemento `form`

Comment: Preciso que seja gerada uma URL pois o usuário pode fazer consultas futuras diretamente.

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli Editei minha resposta. O seu caso se encaixa no último exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, no caso ele da um GET para o arquivo api.php, só que não pode mandar para ele, o arquivo api.php tem que funcionar na mesma página do form, abaixo dele. O arquivo api.php faz a consulta e retorna no form.php

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli editei minha resposta

Comment: Me desculpe a minha inexperiencia mas ele esta indagando que não existe a variavel URL  na linha const URL = new URL(location.href);

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli Desculpe-me o erro. Corrigir o código.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Vou estudar mais sobre o assunto! =)

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli Se possível marca como resolvido, assim outros usuários podem visualizar mais facilmente a resposta durante uma busca.